# How can I lock a database in MySQL so that >1 instances of same user are prohibited?

Tags: mysql, locking

If I use 
    flush tables with read lock;
to lock all my tables, but I have >1 processes who are using the same username & password to access the database, how can I tell MySQLd to only allow one client at a time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think you need it, but tou can change the `max_user_connections` limit for the user and set it to 1:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-resources.html

Comment: Ah... I was mistaken. Two clients using the same user/pass can block each other just fine.